# Python map points on a map based on city

Tags: python

I have a list of cities on python list:

```
Citylist = ["Lexington, KY", "New York, NY", "Tampa FL"]
```

How can add these points on map (preferably an interactive map) using python? Is there a way that I can do this using google maps or another service but send the data straight from python code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The application you are describing is very complex. It certainly isn't a one liner in python.

This library can help you get coordinates for city names.

[Google Maps Python client library](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python)

This library can help you plot data on a map.

[Basemap Python library](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted!